How can I change window.location?
According to the locale value, language information comes after the domain name in the URL. For example, when it is tr, it is http://127.0.0.1:3000/tr/home. When it is English, it is http://127.0.0.1:3000/en/home. When locale tr comes, I want to do tr. When en gfel, I want to use en. I also want it to preserve any value that comes after the grammar.
In the examples above, there is /home, but it can also be other paths in the URL.
How can I change part of the location URL?

Make the server direct to a language infix based on language header information? This is really a server thing, not specifically a "javascript" or even "window.location" thing.

In JavaScript, you can access the URL information with
const foo = window.location.href;
//http://127.0.0.1:3000/tr/home

from here, you can convert it to a URL object to access individual pieces of the URL.
let url = new URL(foo);

If you have a consistent URL structure, you can use string manipulation to access different pieces of the url. e.g.
let segments = url.pathname.split("/");
//segments[0] = "tr"
//segments[1] = "home"

Lastly, you can change some piece of the URI, rebuild the url, and set the window location to the new URL.
segments[0] = "en";
url.pathname = segments.join("/");

window.location.href = url.toString();

